# Mongoldb find documents which contains more than one field off 8 fields

Tags: mongodb

There is a data corruption occurred in the data source.

We have fields a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h
All are integer values either 0 or 1

One document should have only one field with value 1 out of 8 fields. Due to corruption, it has more than one field with value 1.

How do I find documents which contains more than one fields present?

I thought of doing the below - add all eight fields and check whether the sum is greater than 1

Comment: You can not do sum, as you've 0's !! Do you've any other fields in docs apart from one in or a set of those 8 ? Like example I , k, L, forget about `_id` which is default..

Comment: @whoami I have other fields also. How does sum not work?

Comment: let's say if you add a:1 + b:0 gives 1, then how many fields do you assume ?

Comment: @whoami I need documents where sum > 1 which means more than one value is 1 out of that 8 fields.

Comment: So mean you're ok with having a doc like this :: `{_id:123, a:1,b:0,c:0}` but not like this `{_id:1234, a:1,b:0,c:0, d:1}` ? Ok question is a bit unclear..

Comment: @whoami Yes Exactly. I would like to randomly set d:0 in this case or a:0.

Comment: Are you asking for query or checking for better option ? what is your MongoDB version ?

Comment: If any better option, it would be great. I have the query to do it but not sure whether it is technically correct and not sure how to remove the random one

Comment: Sum sounds like a good option to me.

Answer (score 0):

if I understand you correctly you can just add all the fields and then match all the docs that have a count more then one, something like this

```
db.getCollection("your coll").aggregate([
{$project:{
    count_feilds_values:{ $add: [ "$a", "$b" ,"$c"] }
}},
{$match:{count_feilds_values:{$gt:1}}}])
```

Comment: Thanks. I got this. I am looking for a solution to delete or set to 0 on random value with 1

Comment: @Gibbs : What is your mongoDB version ? Amit - this query would not give required o/p !! Check this :: https://mongoplayground.net/p/QLC_762SwRR , Also OP has already got a query for this !!!

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve that with MongoDB aggregation with `$objectToArray` + `$filter`  operators:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $addFields: {
      tmp: {
        $filter: {
          input: {
            $objectToArray: "$$ROOT"
          },
          cond: {
            $eq: [
              "$$this.v",
              1
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $match: {
      $expr: {
        $ne: [
          {
            $size: "$tmp"
          },
          1
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $unset: "tmp"
  }
])
```

[MongoPlayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/_teAgMBVGC-)